# Angular material mat-tab-label

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to access name of the sequence from selectedTabChange event

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onSequenceChangeEvent($event, sequence)">

<mat-tab  *ngFor="let sequence of sequencesForSelectedScope">

    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span>{{sequence.sequenceName}}</span>
    </ng-template>

</mat-tab>
```

In this event i can access following: sequenceEvent.tab.templateLabel.context
but this context is undefined. How can i set this to e.g. sequence.sequenceName?

Comment: You can use `selectedIndexChange` event and get index number then you can access something like `this.sequencesForSelectedScope[index].sequenceName`. Let me know if this will help.

Comment: Yeah, it is solving my problem but is there any way data to this context of ng-template mat-tab-label. There should be somehting like this

Comment: sorry not getting you

Comment: is there any way to bind data to this context*

Comment: means you want to add tab in current tabs or you want to change tab name of existing data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way to do this but it's a bit of a hack. If you assign your 'sequence' data to the 'label' input of the tab, you can get it from the MatTabChangeEvent. This only works because you are using template labels so you can 'repurpose' the label input:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onSequenceChangeEvent($event)">

<mat-tab *ngFor="let sequence of sequencesForSelectedScope" [label]="sequence">

    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span>{{sequence.sequenceName}}</span>
    </ng-template>

</mat-tab>

onSequenceChangeEvent(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  console.log(event.tab.textLabel.sequenceName);
}
```

Comment: Works, may be useful. Thank you.

Comment: This is great, it solved my issue about getting the unique id of each selected tab as I can now pass a whole object to the label.